# Adding Font Awesome in Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, font-awesome

I'am using Font Awesome in my Windows Phone 8 App.
I have added a part of the unicode in the database (for example `f000`).
In my code I add "\u" to complete the unicode. I add it like this:

```
_model.ContentImage = @"\u" + rec.UniContentImage;
```

When I'm debugging it and add a breakpoint, the `contentimage` is filled with `"\\uf000"`(in debugger).
And the font will not be displayed. When I'am changing the content in contentimage(in debugger) to `"\uf000"` awesome font is displayed correctly.

Does anyone know how I can add font awesome correctly and dynamically in c#?

Comment: Are you getting a single empty-box character: '[]'? This means the custom font hasn't been loaded properly.

Comment: Nope when running I just get the string like "uf164". But I've tried your solution and that one was working for me. I didn't tried to convert it like that.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will load the FontAwesome custom font for use in Windows 8.1 Universal apps:

```
FontFamily customFont = new FontFamily("ms-appx:///Assets/FontAwesome.otf#FontAwesome");
textBlock.FontFamily = customFont;
textBlock.Text = "\uf164"; // thumbs up!
```

NB: Set the 'FontAwesome.otf' Properties:

- Build Action: 'Content'
- Copy to Output Directory: 'Do not copy'

Also here is the Data model method I use to return Unicode string for Binding (where this.code is "\uf164"):

```
public String unicode
    {
        get
        {
            String codePoint = this.code.Substring(2); // remove '\u' => "f164";
            int unicode = int.Parse(codePoint, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            String unicodeString = char.ConvertFromUtf32(unicode).ToString();
            return unicodeString; // "\uf164"
        }
    }
```